# Cannot format given object as a Date using LocaleDateTime.now

Tags: java, android

Why do I get an error when I try using this code:

```
get() {
    current = LocalDateTime.now()
    val sharedPreferences = ctx.getSharedPreferences(COMMON_MANAGER, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    val formatter = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd")
    val formatted = formatter.format(current)
    return sharedPreferences.getString("currentDate", formatted)
}
```

It says cannot format given object a date. I have a value of `"2022-01-10T14:55:18.523"` in the variable `current`.

[image]

EDIT

I tried using this code :

```
current = LocalDateTime.now()
        val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd")
        val formatted = formatter.format(current)
        return sharedPreferences.getString("currentDate", formatted)
```

But it gives me an error like so:

[image]

Comment: `LocalDateTime`  is a part of java8 while `SimpleDateFormat` is old api . Shouldn't you be using `DateTimeFormatter`  if you using java8 instead of mixing both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `DateTimeFormatter` instead of `SimpleDateFormat`

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd");
        String result = formatter.format(now);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please see my edit. I tried this.

Answer (score 1):

You are experiencing this error because you are using a `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` to format a `java.time.LocalDateTime`.

I don't think that's possible, but even if it is you will be best adviced not to mix those two apis.

You should instead use a `DateTimeFormatter` and due the pattern you have used in your `SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd")` I would replace the lines

```
val formatter = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd")
val formatted = formatter.format(current)
```

with these

```
val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu/MM/dd")
val formatted = current.format(formatter)
```

Comment: I tried this. But it gives me an error. Please see my edit. Thank you.

Comment: @Ibanez1408 Have you imported the ThreeTen ABP? If yes and your `LocalDateTime` is from that library, change the import to the **required** one from the error message.